Script not detecting when a player with a set ID joins. Luau
For some reason a simple script that I wrote, that should call a function whenever a player joins, which after that checks if the players ID is one of the either.
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)

    print("player join")
    if player.UserId == 3193848005 or 2601513514 then
        
        print("owner join")
        ms.stamina.Value = 250
        ms.maxstamina.Value = 250
        ms.recover.Value = 10

    end
end)

As well as I understand, a local script runs after you launch the server, and join. Which means that it can't utilise PlayerAdded if YOU join. My problem is that the changes still have to remain client sided, so that the stats only change for the player that joined if he is either of above UserIds. Does anyone has an answer?

I cannot make sense of your post. Your heading says "leaves", your body says "joins" . I'm no roblox expert. I would assume that player stats are being managed by the server, not the client. also your condition is always true. you need to write `if player.UserId == 123 or player.UserId == 456'   other wise you're oring with a number which is alway true, making your condition always true regardless the userid.
I would also assume that the server treats the host as any other player so joining your own server should trigger the same events for the host.

Not really, stats are being managed by the local script, which is also doing the job of managing the combat system. Basically all changes to module script values are client sided. My script basically should've set the stats differently if the players User ID is matching with the ones that are shown here. LocalScripts trigger after the player joins, which means that they can't utilise PlayerAdded. Which is the reason I made the post in the first place. I need an alternative for PlayerAdded in this situation, as it can't be activated by the player that joins.

The condition is also not always true. It's only true if Users ID is matching.

as I said I'm no Roblox expert, but you shouldn't try to educate me about simple boolean logic. I even explained to you why it is always true. how can you argue that?  player.UserId == 3193848005 or 2601513514 is always true as 2601513514 is always true.   false or true is true, true or true is true, true or false is true. did you even read the manual? it explicitly explains the case you're mentioning.

shouldn't stats go into StarterPlayerScripts or StarterCharacterScripts?  if your event does not fire you can always call the event handling functioin manually btw.

There is another way to detect when a specific player joins, and it is by checking if there is any players (in game.Players) called "MorelvalVoid" or "Morelval1". Here is an example:
print("player join")
local MorelvalVoid = game.Players:FindFirstChild("MorelvalVoid")
local Morelval1 = game.Players:FindFirstChild("Morelval1")

while task.wait(0,1) do
    if MorelvalVoid or Morelval1 then
        print("owner")
        -- Your code here
    else
        task.wait(30)
        print("not owner")
    end
end


